# Hashrockets in schema.rb after a migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After runnings on migrations on Rails 6.1.4.6, and Ruby 2.7, the `db/schema.rb` is changed to the old format of hash rockets as shown by the `git diff` below:

```
-    t.geometry "column", limit: { srid: 1234, type: "st_point" }
+    t.geometry "column", limit: {:srid=>1234, :type=>"st_point"}
```

Any ideas how to change it back to using the newer Ruby way (ie. not with hash rockets)?

Comment: Before you change `db/schema.rb` . you should run `rails db:rollback` . After that, you change to `migration` and `rails run db:migration`

Comment: This might be a complete waste of effort. By the time you're using Postgis you're very likely going to need to switch to SQL schema dumps in the near future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the exact same issue all of a sudden, messed up my whole `schema.rb`. Turns out it was somehow linked to a gem I recently added, [SchemaValidations](https://github.com/SchemaPlus/schema_validations). Uninstalling it temporarily and then running the migration helped. So check your recently installed gems, especially if they have something to do with ActiveRecord.